# javascript Promise not wait Promise.all

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, es6-promise

So *getAstronautsData* make request to API then return array of promises. This promises mast make request to Wiki API and parse response in object. Then *exampleAsyncFunc* must wait all  promises and return one big object with all info about Astronauts.
But if I use *Promise.all* function ending and console is clear.

```
function getAstronautsData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getData('http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json', "http", (data) => {
            resolve(data) // get Astronauts list from API
        })
    }).then((astronautsList) => {
        return astronautsList.people.map((person => // return array of promises 
            new Promise(resolve => {
                getWikiData(person.name, (data) => { // request on Wiki API
                    resolve({info: data.extract, img: data.thumbnail.source})
                })
            })
        ))
    })
}


async function exampleAsyncFunc (){
    let promisesList = await getAstronautsData()
    // next code just few variant was i try
    let data = await Promise.all(promisesList)// it's not working.
    console.log(data) 

    Promise.all(promisesList).then(data => console.log(data)) //it's not working. Function display nothing

    
    promisesList.forEach((promise) =>  { //it's working but not so elegant
        promise.then(data => console.log(data))
    })

}

exampleAsyncFunc ()

function getWikiData(searhTerm, callback) {
    getData(getUrlString(searhTerm), "https", (data) => {
        const regex = new RegExp(searhTerm.replaceAll(" ", ".*"));
        for (let page in data.query.pages) {
            if (data.query.pages[page].title === searhTerm || regex.test(data.query.pages[page].title)) {
                callback(data.query.pages[page])
                return
            }else{
                callback(null)
            }


        }

    })
}
```

Comment: You are not rejecting anything. I think that's why you don't see anything, because they reject silently

Comment: Is the function `exampleAsyncFunc` exactly as you have it in your test case. Because it does not make sense having both `let data = await Promise.all(promisesList)` and `promisesList.forEach((promise) =>  {` at the same time in the same function in that order and having the `forEach` working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240901/discussion-between-mwo-and-t-niese).

Comment: The problem is most certainly within the `getWikiData` function. The request of the data is likely failing for one of those requests, and the promise stays pending due to that as you don't handle the error case (looks like you can't handle the error case because the callback does not seem to have an error parameter). The `getData` seems to be also prone to that problem.

Comment: @t.niese OK, i add catch in all place where i can. It's don't help

Comment: @t.niese I write three variant, of course i use just one

Comment: @MWO OK, i add catch in all place where i can. It's don't help

Comment: @VitaliiRomanenko `I write three variant, of course i use just one` ok then your observation indicates that at least one `getWikiData` for some reason takes extremely long or fails. And that you don't handle that error case in `getWikiData` correctly (you should pass the error to the callback). `OK, i add catch in all place where i can. It's don't help` you most certainly don't do the error handling correctly. The `catch` won't help if the error is ignored in `getWikiData`.

Comment: @VitaliiRomanenko you shouldn't write the same comment multiple times to target multiple persons.

Comment: @t.niese Thank's about multiple comment but i add catch after all promises and no one is work

Comment: @VitaliiRomanenko adding `catch` in the shown code won't help as you don't `reject` if `getWikiData` fails. As I said, the problem is with the `getWikiData` it either somehow returns an error on failure which you don't handle with a `reject` or if you have written `getWikiData` yourself you do not handle the error correctly within that function.

Comment: The code you have presented is working.The problem must be in code you haven't shared. So can you share `getWikiData` source code?

Comment: @trincot add getWikiData to question

Comment: OK, can you provide enough code for us to reproduce the issue?

Comment: `getWikiData` uses `getData` which - as mentioned earlier - also suffers the same problem, so you need to also show `getData`.

Comment: @t.niese i fixed my problem and added answer. Thanks for help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem was in API (in API one of astronauts have name `"Tom Marshburn"` but on Wiki his page have title `"Thomas Marshburn"`) and function `getWikiData` not return any data on error. So i fixed this problem.
Thanks you all for you help!!!

Comment: That does not really fix the underlying problem. You really should fix you `getData` function and `getAstronautsData` to handle errors and pass those to the callback.

Comment: Thank you, i know about errors handling, this code was a prototype for my project, and all errors handling, and another problems, i will fix later.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using `Promise.all` correctly, but if *any* of the Promises in `Promise.all` rejects, then overall `Promise.all` promise will reject too and nothing will happen, where in your `forEach` version it'll simply skip those promises silently and move on to the next entries.

Likewise if any of the promises in the list stays pending: if so then the `Promise.all` promise will never resolve. This could be because you have a long list of return values and the whole list takes a longer-than-expected time to resolve, or because your `getWikiData` call encounters an error and you don't pass that out to reject that particular promise in your array.

You can debug this behavior by ensuring that each of your calls to `then` is followed by `.catch(console.error)` (or some more robust error handler).

Answer (score 0):

Let me first disclose that I am a big promise partisan and frankly deplore callbacks.  The implication here is that I would not have written your `getData` and `getWikiData` with callbacks.

I will also point out that I second what @t.niese said in the comments: `Because it does not make sense having both let data = await Promise.all(promisesList) and promisesList.forEach((promise) =>  {`.

Anyway, your code is unnecessarily complex and can be simplified like so:

```
function getAstronautsData(callback) {
    getData('http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json', "http", data => {
        callback(data.people.map(person =>
            new Promise(resolve => {
                getWikiData(person.name, data => {
                    resolve(data);
                })
            }))
        )
    })
}

function exampleAsyncFunc (){
    getAstronautsData(promises => {
        Promise.all(promises)
            .then(result => {
                //result will contain those resolved promises
                console.log(result);
            })
    });
}

exampleAsyncFunc ()
```

Notice that I am passing a callback to `getAstronautsData` and call it from inside that function with the array of promises you ultimately want to resolve. No need for `async` here either as you can see.

Comment: Thanks but it's still not working)) script wait few second and then end